# DotNetNuke 6 Module Development

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I am totally new to dotnetnuke and have installed dnn6 comunity edition. i m trying to develop a dnn module to.

1. Display Detailed News
2. Display top 8 news on homepage (from where navigate to the Display Detailed News)

i am using installed web starter kit as template and vs .net2010 and development env.

In this regard i have 3 questions.

1. How to add **user control** to display **TOP 8 NEWS** to the existing module so that i may add it as **New module from control** in dnn site?
2. How to display different category of news in this control on different page?

Answer (score 1):

1) You will need to either create a new Module Definition, add the Control as another option to an existing Definition, or even define a completely new module on the extensions page that uses the new ASCX file. Most likely you will do the first option, adding to a ModuleDef to existing module. Then when you add the module to a page, you'll actually get two different modules loaded on the page. You can delete the one you don't want to use. The DNN blog module does this with like 5 or 6 different controls that get added to the page.

2) You'll want to configure Module Settings for the ASCX that control which category the articles come from.

If you really are serious about doing module development I would encourage you to check out my VS Templates, instead of the starter kit You can find the DNN6/VS2010 templates in the .9 release http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/releases/view/93348

All the newer releases are for Visual Studio 2012 (even the free versions work though, so check those out)